# Non standard extension of real numbers via nonprincipal ultra filters

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, fields, nonstandard-analysis

Assume  That $U,V$ are two  filters on the natural  number $\mathbb{N}$.
We say that $U$ is  equivalent to $V$ if there  is a  bijection $\phi: \mathbb{N} \to  \mathbb{N}$  such that $\tilde{\phi}(U)=V$ where $\tilde{\phi}:P(\mathbb{N}) \to  P(\mathbb{N})$ is  the  natural extension of  $\phi$ to the  power set $P(\mathbb{N})$.
Let $U,V$ be two  non principal ultra filter on $\mathbb{N}$.

Let $\mathbb{R}^*_{U}$ and $\mathbb{R}^*_{V}$ be the corresponding [nonstandard extension of real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis#Basic_definitions) associated with $U$ and $V$, respectively.

Assume that  $\mathbb{R}^*_{U}$ and $\mathbb{R}^*_{V}$  are isomorphic as  fields. Does  this  imply that $U$ and  $V$ are  equivalent filters?

My  apology in advance, if the  question is  elementary. The  question arose me about  17 years  ago when I was  trying  to  understand the  application of  non standard  analysis  to ordinary  differential equations.

Comment: I think it's known that under CH, all ultrapowers $\mathbb{R}_U$ are isomorphic. Maybe somebody more familiar known more about this.

Comment: A question that addresses the result mentioned by YCor can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136720/why-does-ch-imply-that-there-is-a-unique-ultrapower-of-mathbbn).

Comment: Just to finish the proof, there are always nonequivalent nonprincipal ultrafilters (since there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$-many nonprincipal ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$ and only $2^{\aleph_0}$-many bijections from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself), so under CH the answer is no.  But I think the answer is probably no just in ZFC.

Comment: Some articles related to this can be found in [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/719131/72694). There are $2^c$ ultrafilters but also $2^c$ non-isomorphic fields when $\neg CH$, so straightforward "counting" does not seem to allow one to decide.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/280935/72694 is a related answer by @AndreasBlass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand the question is still open under $\neg CH$, namely whether isomorphism of hyperreal fields implies equivalence of filters (up to permutation of index set). Perhaps one can try the following approach.

In a universe $V$ satisfying $CH$, we can take two inequivalent filters and obtain fields that are automatically isomorphic by the result of Erdos &Co mentioned in the MSE post linked in the comments above. Now the idea is to take a forcing extension $V^F$ satisfying $\neg CH$.

One can't transfer naively the construction of the hyperreal field to $V^F$ because the ultrafilter is not definable, but perhaps one can work with the definable hyperreal field of Kanovei and Shelah (which exploits a *huge* index set using all ultrafilters simultaneously, thereby defeating non-definability). Perhaps one can specify two variants of the Kanovei-Shelah construction whether the ideals are not equivalent but the quotient fields will be by the Erdos-type argument, and then take a forcing extension to exhibit a similar phenomenon under $\neg CH$.